# MySQL update a table from a result of a select

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
__________________________________
|      products_description       |
__________________________________
 products_id | products_description
----------------------------------

__________________________________
|     products_to_categories     |
__________________________________
  products_id  | id_categories     
----------------------------------
```

I need to update "products_description" on the products that have '309' as id_categories.
So I guess I need to make a

```
SELECT to products_to_categories WHERE id_categories = 309
```

and with those results make an

```
UPDATE to "products_description" to SET "my string" WHERE 
products_description.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id.
```

I have search everywhere but I can't find the example I need, and clearly I'm not good enough with MySQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE products_description 
SET products_description = 'YOUR TEXT' 
WHERE product_id IN (
  SELECT products_id FROM products_to_categories WHRE id_categories = 309
)
```

Btw, try better names for your tables and columns. If your table is called products_descriptions then there is no need to name one of its columns `products_description` you can just name it `description`.

Answer (score 0):

Hellow I think you have to write a subquery. 
for Example.

```
UPDATE products_description
SET products_description = (SELECT your_column FROM products_to_categories WHERE id_categories = products_description.products_id LIMIT 1)
```